# One To Many LINQ Joins Across Nested Collections

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I have a development scenario where I am joining two collections with Linq; a single list of column header objects which contain presentation metadata, and an enumeration of kv dictionaries which result from a web service call. I can currently iterate (`for`) through the dictionary enumeration, and join the single header list to the current kv dictionary without issue. After joining, I emit a curated array of dictionary values for each iteration.

What I would like to do is eliminate the `for` loop, and join the single header list directly to  the entire enumeration. I understand the 1-to-1 collection join pretty well, but the 1-to-N syntax is eluding me.

**Details**

I have the following working method:

```
public void GetQueryResults(DataTable outputTable)
{
    var odClient = new ODataClient(UrlBase);
    var odResponse = odClient.FindEntries(CommandText);

    foreach (var row in odResponse)
    {
        var rowValues = OutputFields
            .Join(row, h => h.Key, r => r.Key, 
                (h, r) => new { Header = h, ResultRow = r })
            .Select(r => r.ResultRow.Value);

        outputTable.Rows.Add(rowValues.ToArray());
    }
}
```

`odResponse` contains `IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, object>>`; `OutputFields` contains `IList<QueryField>`; the `.Join` produces an enumeration of anons containing matched field metadata (`.Header`) and response kv pairs (`.ResultRow`); finally, the `.Select` emits the matched response values for row consumption. The `OutputField` collection looks like this:

```
class QueryField
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
}
```

Which is declared as:

```
public IList<QueryField> OutputFields { get; private set; }
```

By joining the collection of field headers to the response rows, I can pluck just the columns I need from the response. If the header keys contain { "size", "shape", "color" } and the response keys contain { "size", "mass", "color", "longitude", "latitude" }, I will get an array of values for { "size", "shape", "color" }, where *shape* is null, and the *mass*, *longitude*, and *latitude* values are ignored. For the purposes of this scenario, I am not concerned with ordering. This all works a treat.

**Problem**

What I'd like to do is refactor this method to return an enumeration of value array rows, and let the caller manage the consumption of the data:

```
public IEnumerable<string[]> GetQueryResults()
{
    var odClient = new ODataClient(UrlBase);
    var odResponse = odClient.FindEntries(CommandText);

    var responseRows = //join OutputFields to each row in odResponse by .Key

    return responseRows;
}
```

**Followup Question**

Would a Linq-implemented solution for this refactor require an immediate scan of the enumeration, or can it pass back a lazy result? The purpose of the refactor is to improve encapsulation *without* causing redundant collection scans. I can always build imperative loops to reformat the response data the hard way, but what I'd like from Linq is something like a closure.

Thanks heaps for spending the time to read this; any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what you mean but could it be you're meaning something like this?

```
public IEnumerable<object[]> GetQueryResults()
{

    var odClient = new ODataClient(UrlBase);
    var odResponse = odClient.FindEntries(CommandText);


    // i'd rather you linq here.
    var responseRows = from row in odResponse
                       select new object[] 
                       { 
                           from field in row
                           join outputfield in OutputFields 
                               on field.Key equals outputfield.Key
                           select field.Value 
                       };

    return responseRows;

}
```

Instead of filling a DataTable. This will create an array of objects and filling it with field.Value where the field.Key exists in the outputfields. The whole thing is encapsulated in a `IEnumerable`. *(from row in odResponse)*

Usage:

```
var responseRows = GetQueryResults2();

foreach(var rowValues in responseRows)
    outputTable.Rows.Add(rowValues);
```

The trick here is, within one query you iterate a list and create a subquery on the fields and stores the subquery result directly in a `object[]`. The `object[]` is only created when the `responseRows` is iterated. This is the answer on your second question I think -> *the Lazy result*.